# Elasticsearch response times are high even when query time is low

Tags: elasticsearch, zfs

I'm seeing high response times on elasticsearch searches (`took` is 5000ms) but if I check profile, query time is low ~15ms. I think this only happens when the request rate is high, but CPU is also far from fully saturated (~50%).

I'm requesting many items (`size=4096`), but I set `_source=false` to exclude document data. If I lower `size` to 10, responses are very fast (`took=35`). If I add `from=4096, size=10` responses are still very fast. I'm using `track_total_hits=true`, but removing doesn't seem to make any difference. The index is quite small (<2GB) and should definitely fit in cache (96GB RAM). Heap size is around 75% most of the time. CPU usage varies between 20-80%.

I've tried looking at perf_events and I'm seeing a lot of cpu (40 cores at ~30% in `osq_lock()`) coming from ZFS reads locks, so I suspect this might be a problem with the filesystem.

##### `perf top` during slow response times

[image]

I would not expect fs reads to be the bottleneck. I'm a bit surprised it's reading from disk at all, I would assume that would not be necessary when `_source=false`? I'm really just interested in the document ids. Could it be that ZFS is just not suited for Elasticsearch?

Software versions:

- Elasticsearch 7.10.1 (official docker image)
- ZFS: 0.7.8